# how to turn nested foreach loop with C# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a private method as follow:

```
private Dictionary<string, decimal> GetRateByYear(IEnumerable<EmployerCu> cuList, 
    HashSet<long> activeCuSet, int year)
{
    Dictionary<string, decimal> cuDict = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
    foreach (EmployerCu cu in cuList)
    {
        decimal rate = 0;    // rate maintains 0 if year is not match

        if (activeCuSet.Contains(cu.PayrollClassId))    // ignore inactive CUs
        {
            foreach (Rate r in cu.Rates)
            {
                if (r.Year == year)
                {
                    rate =  r.Value / Percentile;
                }
            }

            cuDict.Add(cu.Code.ToString(), rate);
        }        
    }

    return cuDict;
}
```

The logic works as expected. I just wanna challenge myself a little bit more with C# Linq.
I am trying to filter the input "cuList" with "activeCuSet", and add the cu.code and the rate for this year in a dictionary.

Here is the data model:

```
public class EmployerCu
{
    public long ClassId { get; set; }
    public long Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long PayrollClassId { get; set; } 
    public Rate[] Rates { get; set; }
}

public class Rate
{
    public RateType Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public long Year { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Jawad I am pretty new to Linq. And I am interested in the syntax, and try to summarize the rules when to use it or when not to use it for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truth be told, not everything needs to be *Linq*. Sometimes it just makes code less maintainable and readable.

However this is potentially what a *Linq* solution would look like using [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8)

> Creates a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
private Dictionary<string, decimal> GetRateByYear(IEnumerable<EmployerCu> cuList, HashSet<long> activeCuSet, int year)
  => cuList.Where(x => activeCuSet.Contains(x.PayrollClassId))
                .ToDictionary(
                    x => x.Code,
                    x => x.Rates.LastOrDefault(y => y.Year == year)?.Value / Percentile ?? 0);
```

<sub>***Note*** : i used `LastOrDefault` as that was what your loop was doing</sub>

Comment: @Terence most likely not, at some point something is looping. there is a real chance its less performant